Trying to search for rows containing matching data to move to a new sheet from a list of values - not working
I'm trying to copy every row of a sheet to a new sheet where the values in a particular column ("G") match a list of values on a different sheet column ("A") but then end of a long wait ends with a single row being copied, presumably the last found row.
Here's the code I'm using:
Sub FindData()
'Run code to grab all sample data matching to chassis numbers

Dim s As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim NARow As Integer
NARow = 2

For s = 2 To 2920
    For x = 2 To 24842
        If Sheets("Serials").Cells(s, 1).Value = Sheets("RawData").Cells(x, 7).Value Then
            Sheets("RawData").Rows(x).EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("FinalData").Range("A" & NARow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            NARow = NARow + 1
        End If
    
    Next x
Next s
End Sub


Are you sure there is more than one match? Do you need to do this in VBA? It seems a lookup may well do what you want. Side note: using Sheets("FinalData").Rows(NARow).EntireRow = Sheets("RawData").Rows(x).EntireRow instead of going via the pasteboard may speed things up.

Thanks, I'll give that a try. Yes there are between 1 and 29 matches in the list of data for each chassis/serial number

Side note: there are several posts on how to find the last row in a sheet, this might be a better option instead of hardcoding the last rows in your macro

Wrote it as a generic procedure.  Using last rows on both tables, and exiting the inner loop when a match is found.
Sub Main()
    Call PopulateMatchedData(Sheets("Serials"), 1, Sheets("RawData"), 7, Sheets("FinalData"))
End Sub

Sub PopulateMatchedData(ByRef wsSheet1 As Worksheet, ByVal iColSheet1 As Integer, _
                        ByRef wsSheet2 As Worksheet, ByVal iColSheet2 As Integer, _
                        ByRef wsDestination As Worksheet, Optional DataStartRow As Integer = 2)
'Compares two work sheets for a value.  If iCol_ matches resulting row in wsSheet2 is moved to wsDestination

    Dim oCurRowSheet1 As Long           ' Row Counter for Sheet 1
    Dim oCurRowSheet2 As Long           ' Row Counter for Sheet 2
    Dim oCurRowDestination As Long      ' Row Counter for destination sheet
    oCurRowDestination = DataStartRow
    
    ' Loops for each sheet start with offset provided defaulting to row 2, until the last used row of that sheet.
    For oCurRowSheet1 = DataStartRow To wsSheet1.Cells(wsSheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For oCurRowSheet2 = DataStartRow To wsSheet2.Cells(wsSheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If wsSheet1.Cells(oCurRowSheet1, iColSheet1).Value = wsSheet2.Cells(oCurRowSheet2, iColSheet2).Value Then
                'On Match Copy entire sheet2 row into Destination Sheet
                wsSheet2.Rows(oCurRowSheet2).EntireRow.Copy wsDestination.Rows(oCurRowDestination)
                oCurRowDestination = oCurRowDestination + 1
                Exit For    ' Leave the inner for loop if Match was found
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub


This is still only adding a single line to the "FinalData" sheet. I know running 2000 odd loops looking through 12,000 odd rows of data for a match and copying them across is an arduous task, but it seems like it's only finding one match, copying that and ending the loops altogether.

What is the id (matching value) of the entry that's repeating?  Is it a blank field?

6 digit serial number. There may be a few values empty and a few that are only 4, but maximum 6.
